# SvelteKit loads favicon every page request

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Does anybody have the same problem with SvelteKit? Why does it load the favicon on every page request? [see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXjgz.png)

Comment: I have the very same problem.

Comment: For anyone that stubles across this issue that is using the bun runtime, I tried to resolve this for hours but ultimately had to switch back to node [on which it was fixed back in July](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/3748). I haven't seen this issue since switching back to node.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have this issue with favicon. I'm setting favicon in top most +layout.svelte via `<svelte:head>` like this:

```
<svelte:head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg" href={icon-path} />
</svelte:head>
```